# SQL Server Management Studio 2008 - Timeout Expired error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I'm running a query for a view from the View Designer screen in SSMS / SQL Server 2008R2 and I'm getting a strange error:

```
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Error Message: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the 
operation or the server is not responding
```

I've been doing web-searches for the last hour or so and couldn't find any working fixes for it. I've found a few posts which suggested to change the Timeout for the Designer by going to `Tools - Options - Designers` and changing the `Transaction time-out after` value to a greater value.

When running my query in a normal Query window, it takes about 40 seconds to run and although I've set this value to 90 seconds, it still throws the error.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `I've set this value to 90 seconds` what is this value? where did you set it?

Comment: @M.Ali This value = ***Transaction time-out after*** in *Tools-Options-Designers* in SSMS.

Comment: Well one thing you could consider is to stop using the buggy view designer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I would stop, but it's not me who insists on using it, it's a client who I'm working with. And he wants to run/see the results into the View Designer as he's used to that window, and he'd like to continue from that point with joining with other views he's created. Any suggestions for a workaround on this? (I've never used View Designer that much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found out why the issue occurs in the most common scenarios, which are when you develop an interface in .NET and you need to specify a default time-out time for the session which you use to communicate with SQL Server.

And I assumed that this default time-out is built in the window for View Designer in SQL Server Management Studio.

I observed that the query for the view, which I ran in an ordinary Query window, took about 40 seconds. I timed running the query in the View Designer window, from starting to run the query until the error occurred and the time was aprox. 30 seconds.

This is the point where I decided that if I can't change this default time-out, then I should try to speed up my query. I re-ran the query with displaying the `Actual Execution Plan` and improved the query by reducing the most time/resource consuming operations (in my situation it was a Sort operation - `ORDER BY` on a computed column from my view, which had no index).

I removed the `ORDER BY` as it was not mandatory and the query successfully ran in under 10 seconds in the View Designer window.

In conclusion, if you ever encounter this error and you can't change the time-out time, then you can try to improve the execution time of the query to go below 30 seconds.

Comment: I just added this bug to the "Connect" feedback site. Go vote it up! https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3115872